# difference in "good" and "well" in this sentence

Tags: adverbs, nouns

Which sentence is correct:

> your throw was good
>
> your throw was well

I think that throw is verb so second should be correct ,but the sentence looks odd.

Comment: Related: [When do “well” and “good” mean the same?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/337/9161)

Answer (score 2):

The first one is actually correct.

Here, "throw" is acting as a noun, so you want the adjective (good) rather than the adverb. Your hint here is "your," which always comes before nouns.

Another way to think about is "Your action is good." Action is always a noun, so obviously it uses the adjective. And a throw is a specific action.

Answer (score 0):

Your *first* sentence is OK (it adds the quality of the *adjective* 'good' to the *noun* 'throw'). As for the *second* sentence, you *can't* modify a *noun* with an *adverb* ('well') it is only possible to modify a *verb* with it. Fortunately, by addition of a verb you can transform that sentence into:

> Your throw was **well performed**.